# Adding listener to the marker that pops up Infowindow - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I add a listener to my marker which reads "Hi" when the marker is clicked. My code looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAGcwOypxqebsKcF-A6pZUqDvijKbjltw0&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(61.455019, 23.84559);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: myMap,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click',
      function() 
      {
         var htmlString = "Hi";
         myMarker.openInfoWindowHtml(htmlString);
      }
   );
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think I am going somewhere wrong while calling the addListener event.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation on infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) for the Google Maps API v3, there is no .openInfoWindowHtml method.

[Working example from the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure)

[Working version of your map using v3 syntax](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MarkerListenerA.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in click function...you can replace this code from ur var myMarker.

```
        var myMarker  = new google.maps.Marker({

                position: myLatlng,
                map: myMap,
                title: 'xxxxx'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker  , 'click', function() {
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                infowindow.setContent('Hi');
                infowindow.open(myMap, myMarker);
            });
```